# Is there any software like Windows Device Manager in Ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: 14.04, system-installation, package-management, source-packages

I want to View/Install/Uninstall the System's Default Packages separately like `Device Manager` in Windows.

I wanna list the Systems's Default Packages too.

Is there anything available regarding to that?

How to know the file that belongs to System default file.

Comment: What does the Device Manager have to do with packages? O.o Checkout Synaptic, which might be what you want.

Comment: I want it like list Which could be more helpful. Ex: USB ,Graphics,... and i have get the list of the USB drivers that i have installed. @muru

Comment: See http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/60078/find-out-which-modules-are-associated-with-a-usb-device

Answer (score 2):

From what you describe in your question I think you're looking for three tools hardinfo, synaptic, and galternatives.

hardinfo allows you to see all your hardware and even do a few benchmarks.

[image: Install via the software center] `sudo apt-get install hardinfo`

synaptic gives you a list of software, that can be searched, and sorted by category. It also allows you to install/uninstall and manage software.

[image: Install via the software center] `sudo apt-get install synaptic`

galternatives allows you manage and select the default package to provide a specific service, such as specifying the default version of java to be used.

[image: Install via the software center] `sudo apt-get install galternatives`

Comment: Good point. You understand Windows users better than me :) +1

Comment: @A.B. thanks though I've not been a Windows user for eight years now.

Comment: :) 16 years here