# Reinstall usb drivers like device manager

Tags: drivers, usb, keyboard

My keyboard sometimes (for example when power goes down) behaves a little bit strange, and every time the PC starts, the LED's are off, like it has returned to default settings. On windows I fix this by going to the device manager and reinstalling the drivers of the keyboard (I actually uninstall them and then plug the keyboard in again). After I do this the keyboard returns to normal and keeps the settings each time the PC starts.

How can I do this on Ubuntu? (Uninstall only the keyboard USB drivers though, not everything)

Comment: See if this hepls - https://askubuntu.com/questions/657528/is-there-any-software-like-windows-device-manager-in-ubuntu-14-04

Comment: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DeviceManager

Comment: I have hardinfo installed but I don't see any options for drivers etc...it just lists the hardware

Comment: The drivers are in the kernel as kernel modules. You dont really reinstall them you install a new kernel.

Comment: So what can I do? I want to plug the keyboard again like it has never been on my pc again... Is this possible?

Comment: Not sure as I do not know the problem. To be honest, keyboard sounds buggy as you have this problem on multiple OS. See https://askubuntu.com/questions/178054/laptop-usb-ports-stop-working-how-to-restart-them-without-restarting-the-pc and https://askubuntu.com/questions/206614/usb-slots-stop-working-suddenly-from-time-to-time